# Non standard evaluation (NSE) for dplyr do()

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to implement something like

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% do(mod = lm(mpg ~ disp, data = .))
```

inside a function like this

```
myfun <- function(d, groupvar, x, y) {
  d %>% group_by(groupvar) %>% do(mod = lm(y ~ x, data = .))
}
myfun(mtcars, cyl, disp, mpg)
```

but I cannot understand well enough NSE to do it. I know, for example, that dplyr NSE functions like `group_by` or `summarize` have the associated SE functions `group_by_` and `summarize_` but it seems that `do` has not an associated `do_`.

Comment: Seems like `do_` is planned for `dplyr 0.3.1`: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/718

Comment: `do_` is now included in the github version of `dplyr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
library(lazyeval)
f <- function(d, groupvar, x , y) {
    groupvar <- lazy(groupvar)
    x <- lazy(x)
    y <- lazy(y)
    d %>% group_by_(groupvar) %>%
        do(mod = lm(interp(quote(y ~ x), y = y, x = x), data = .))
}

f(mtcars, cyl, disp, mpg)
# Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
# Groups: <by row>
# 
#   cyl     mod
# 1   4 <S3:lm>
# 2   6 <S3:lm>
# 3   8 <S3:lm>
```